# Ajax throwing fail function... But it does what it should do

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I've got a weird behavior in my PHP/jQuery project.

When I call the Ajax request, it works as intended, but instead of calling the 'done' function, it calls the 'fail' one.

This is my code at the moment.

```
$("#form").submit(function(){

    var _this = $(this);
    var values = {};
    $.each($('#form').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
        values[field.name] = field.value;
    });
  //  _this.button('loading');
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "include/ajax/install_ajax.php",
      data: values,
      dataType: 'json'
    })
      .done(function( msg ) {
        console.log( "Done: " + msg );
      })
      .fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.warn('Xhr: ' + xhr.responseText);
            console.warn('textStatus: ' + textStatus);
            console.warn('errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);

      }); 
});
```

And this is my install_ajax.php

```
<?php

// Chiama le funzioni del sito
require('../functions.php');

// Controlla se è una richiesta AJAX.
is_ajax();


    try {

    $args['db_host'] = $_POST['db_host'];
    $args['db_username'] = $_POST['db_username'];
    $args['db_password'] = $_POST['db_password'];
    $args['db_name'] = $_POST['db_name'];
    $args['admin_email'] = $_POST['admin_email'];
    $args['admin_username'] = $_POST['admin_username'];
    $args['admin_password'] = $_POST['admin_password'];

    $structure = 
    "-- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Struttura della tabella `users`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `username` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `email` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `name` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `surname` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `password` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `admin` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `validated` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;";

    installDB($args['db_host'],$args['db_username'],$args['db_password'],$args['db_name'],$structure);

    createAdmin($args['db_host'],$args['db_username'],$args['db_password'],$args['db_name'],$args['admin_email'], $args['admin_username'], $args['admin_password']);

    createConfig($args['db_name'],$args['db_username'],$args['db_password'],$args['db_host']);
    $return = array();

    $return['success'] = true;

    return_json($return);

} catch (Exception $e) {
   error_log($e->getMessage() . "\n", 3, "/var/tmp/error.log");
}

?>
```

The message warn I get on the console is..

```
core.js:31 Xhr: undefined
core.js:32 textStatus: error
core.js:33 errorThrown: undefined
```

But the table 'users', the config file and the admin user are created however.

How can I fix it?

I will provide the code of the functions on request.

Comment: what does `/var/tmp/error.log` say?

Comment: Absolutely nothing, no error gets printed out.

Comment: you have to be sure that you are actually hitting that URL, ,try to check the `network` tab inside the Chrome inspector to see what the responses are .. just to eliminate the 404 or something similar along the way..

Comment: The network error status is: CANCELED.
Don't know what does it mean, though..

Comment: ok, that means that is jquery error,, now look in console output is there any errors when you submit form

Comment: No errors, only user-defined warn-log on line 31,32,33.
And the request is handled fine, I see the results, the DB is written and the config file is created. Very weird imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the error that you see is that your code submits 2 times.. try to add this line:

```
$("#form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();  //prevent form from submitting, and only do ajax call
    var _this = $(this);
    // etc code..
}
```

this should work ok now..

Comment: This works perfectly!

The behaviour would be the same if it was a $("#button").click ?
Or there aren't differences between a Submit Event with a preventDefault and a normal Click Event on the button?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
    var _this = $(this);
    var values = {};
    $.each($('#form').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
        values[field.name] = field.value;
    });
  //  _this.button('loading');
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "include/ajax/install_ajax.php",
      data: values,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response){
        alert(response);
      },
      error: function(error){
        alert(error);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: [Object object]

Comment: `echo json_encode($return)` use this code in your php instead of return_json

Comment: This is not working too.. Sorry dass..
[Object object] fail response, as always

Comment: Could you inspect element the network to see the error?

Answer (score 0):

try to return your output using

```
return json_encode($return);
```

instead of

```
return_json($return);
```

Comment: This is not working too.. Sorry odai.. [Object object] fail response, as before

Answer (score 0):

```
    In PHP
    in try 
    statement add echo json_encode(array('success'=>'1')); die;

and in Catch statement add echo json_encode(array('failed'=>'1')); die;


    replace your jquery submit code with below

    $("#form").submit(function(submitEvent){
        submitEvent.preventDefault();
        var _this = $(this);    
      //  _this.button('loading');
        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "include/ajax/install_ajax.php",
          data: _this.serializeArray(),
          dataType: 'JSON',
          success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
          },
          error: function(error){
            console.warn(error);
          }
        });      
    });

and check browser console
```